# Tags field not showing in Windows Explorer Details Pane when *null*

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu, tags

I want to add tags to some files as seamlessly as possible, without the "hassle"of opening context menu / properties / details. The Details Pane works perfectly... to edit the existing tags, because the tags field only shows when there are already added tags. Any idea about how to change this behaviour (as in showing thus allowing to edit the tags field even when null).

I've tried to add a direct access to tags in the context menu using this method https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/ but it hasn't worked. Whether due to the same "not showing if null" behaviour, or because I did something wrong, I don't know.

No 3rd party applications unless they allow me to set the tags directly from the context menu AND see those tags in windows explorer / the details pane.

Answer (score 1):

What filetype are you trying to tag? Only certain types support tags. Those that do have the `Add a tag` prompt when the **Tags** are empty:

[image]

Comment: I hadn't noticed image files show that prompt! I was trying to tag video files. .mp4 don't show the prompt but let you edit it through properties (and then show it in the details pane). I've now realiced that behavior is erratic even between video files. .mkv files show the Tags field in properties, but I can't seem to edit, .avi files don't even show it. I guess a multi-file type Windows Explorer integrated tag system is just not possible? Weird.